# What are the Kotlin Coroutines, How they are different from live data

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am starting to work with new things that are developed by the developer community Android, one of them is **Coroutines**. I have used the LiveData
and I assumed while using them, they are also lifecycle safe, then why coroutines are introduced and how they are different from LiveData. I have seen the video on Coroutines at Youtube, from developer channel, but I don't understand that completely. How Suspend and Resume works better than LiveData.

Comment: "why coroutines are introduced" -- Kotlin is used for things other than Android apps. `LiveData` is an Android thing. "How Suspend and Resume works better than LiveData" -- they are neither "better" nor worse. Coroutines and `LiveData` frequently work together, just as RxJava and `LiveData` frequently work together.

Comment: @CommonsWare if they are not better, then why developers at google are very much talking about them in the IO 2019

Comment: As I wrote, you use `LiveData` and coroutines **together**.

Answer (score 3):

Ok first of all coroutines don't really relate too much with `LiveData` although they might share here and there some concepts. 
Coroutines are used to perform async operation: Retreive data from network, database etc. 
Coroutines can be used as "LiveData" if you are talking in the context of Channels or Flows (which I don't recomend because you will lose the lifecycle in it). With coroutines you can switch to threads easily.

`Suspend` functions are just functions that hold and don't run directly. Any suspending function should be inside a coroutine.

The simplest use case I can give you is this:

```
runBlocking{
 //you are inside of a coroutine
 val data = getDataFromBackground()
}

suspend fun getDataFromBackground(): SomeDataType = receiveSomeData()
```

The `receiveSomeData` method is also marked with `suspend` keyword.

But of course there is a lot more. [The documentation is perfect way to start](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutines-guide.html).

I also have a [personal article](https://medium.com/@stavro96/kotlin-coroutines-the-non-confusing-one-5a47ca799578) about coroutines, you may find them easy there.

There is only one point I can think of that you can replace data with coroutines, and that's using Channels. The view won't be observing for `LiveData` but will be consuming values comming from a channel, created and shared with DI or something.

EDIT: 
If you really want to use LiveData + coroutines please check this [awesome library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) by the Android team.

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines is for asynchronous job. Live Data are used to update your View (Activity & Fragment)